# Deleting Multiple Records from a Firestore Collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter out the documents which are `older than 29 days` and delete millions of them from my database, now I am deleting them by batches using the batch delete but it only allows to delete by the batch size of 500.

Is there a more practical way of deleting millions of records from a collection in a Firestore database without iterating over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to delete documents is to call out each of their IDs using a DocumentReference along with a call to `delete()` or through a batch.  If you don't know their IDs, then you will have to query and iterate.  Firestore does not offer a "delete from ... where ..." operation like SQL.

Short of deleting the entire project, or using the console to delete an entire collection, you don't really have a better option to delete documents in bulk.